# Bizarre behaviour from piping input into `kubectl`

Tags: bash, environment-variables, pipe, kubectl, envsubst

I am trying to substitute environment variables into a .yaml file, and pass the resulting file into `kubectl`:

```
> cat template.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: $K8S_NAMESPACE

> cat .env
K8S_NAMESPACE=leafsheets-staging-pi

> ( set -a; source .env;  envsubst < template.yaml | kubectl apply -f - )
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Why this error?

I got the syntax from https://skofgar.ch/dev/2020/08/how-to-quickly-replace-environment-variables-in-a-file/

### Debugging

`kubectl` works fine like this:

```
> cat pure.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: leafsheets-staging-pi

> kubectl apply -f pure.yaml 
namespace/leafsheets-staging-pi created

> kubectl apply -f pure.yaml 
namespace/leafsheets-staging-pi unchanged
```

And the substitution is working correctly:

```
> envsubst < template.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: leafsheets-staging-pi
```

(This is identical to pure.yaml)

But the command fails:

```
> ( set -a; source .env;  envsubst < template.yaml | kubectl apply -f - )
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

And now the original direct command (which worked before) also fails:

```
> kubectl apply -f pure.yaml 
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Creating a fresh shell, it will work again.

Can anyone explain this bizarre behaviour? Is it a bash issue or a kubectl issue receiving stdin?

### Hack solution

And what is a good workaround? I'm currently doing:

```
> cat template.yaml | envsubst > /tmp/foo.yaml
> kubectl apply -f /tmp/foo.yaml
```

... but it feels very ugly.

Comment: @Inian This is a simplified example. In my actual use case, I have maybe 20 environment variables. So I really don't want to have to specify them manually. And I have shown that the problem is not with `envsubst`. The substitution is being performed correctly.

Comment: I reproduced it without any issues. Could you describe your environment in more details- is it bare-metal/ cloud, os, version. Are there any logs in kubelet (systemctl status kubelet & journactl -u kubelet)?